# SQL Server: Parse error when declaring table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having trouble declaring a Table. By using the following code (SQL server)

```
DECLARE @dates TABLE date;
```

I get the error

```
SQL Error [103010] [S0001]: Parse error at line: 1, column: 16: Incorrect syntax near 'TABLE'.
```

Can someone explain what the problem might be?

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax requires table definition.  Presumably something like:

```
declare @dates table (date date);
```

This declares a table with one column, whose name is `date` and whose type is `date`.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d34f8630a3ea2ce22db8d31d1fe71102) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Though, I get the same error when using above.

Comment: @FAHRB . . . I works fine.  I added a db<>fiddle.

Comment: @FAHRB - from the format of the error message you are clearly using  Azure Data Warehouse - you should mention this when asking questions so people don't waste time providing answers for other editions